# How often are questions deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Is there some sort of warning or time period I should be aware of? I assume several questions that were just deleted had low vote counts, although I don't remember off the top of my head. I mainly ask because I was surprised to lose around 300 points, and I feel like I might have missed a warning or a rule. I thought I remembered reading somewhere on the main meta that questions were deleted automatically, since I know they can be deleted by users too; I assume in the latter case, there's no warning (obviously).

plus, I'll probably save material from answers in advance of a deletion next time since I tend to reuse stuff from question to question. If I get more points again I can just see the deleted answers, but just in case, I thought I'd ask. I looked around on the main meta but couldn't find anything specific. Can someone point me in the right direction there (so as not to repeat an answer that's already somewhere else)?

Comment: I deleted a bunch of questions today that had been closed as off-topic, not-a-real-question, etc. over the last couple of months.  There is no set schedule -- I go through the list when time permits.  I'll check tomorrow what I got rid of and see what questions had the impact. But, that is a consequence of answering a question that is likely to be closed and hence eventually deleted.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Right, in hindsight, some of those were bound to be deleted. The ones that had an impact on me (and the ones with answers I'll save once I'm able) were a question on sticky prices, one about choosing a Forex broker, and a Bitcoin one. I agree they should be deleted if they're not relevant to the site.

Comment: Found those. The Bitcoin one lives on at http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/can-an-asset-defy-the-laws-of-gravity-and-rise-in-price-indefinitely (it was migrated) and I just temporarily undeleted the other two. Please let me know once you've grabbed a copy. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea [This](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/21473/7590) is the Bitcoin one I was referring to. I copied the answers I wanted, though, so you can redelete at will.

Comment: @JohnBension BTW, regarding the "sticky prices" economics post... perhaps you'd be interested in following/supporting the new Economics site proposal.  There was an econ SE before, it didn't work, but the new site proposal has been broadened to appeal to more folks.  See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42351/economics

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Thanks for pointing that out to me; I wasn't aware there had been an economics.SE before, but I'll follow the new proposal and see what comes of it. I'm not sure much of my answer to the forex broker question would really fit on the other one, since the answers to the latter cover all the bases. I have a copy of my answer now, though, so I can work on it and post an answer later.

Comment: John, this is the risk when I find a marginal question interesting. If I feel it's bound to be deleted, it's not really worth it to reply, and I sometimes wait to see how it's going for a few days.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Good point; I need to curb my impatience and not jump on questions immediately!